# React not re-rendering component after page refresh, even if the state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got really weird problem. I mean, to me, really. This is not some kind of "use setState instead of this.state" problem. I'm working on trip planning App. I'm using ContextAPI which provides login information and user data (logged user trips etc ) to the whole app. 
"Schedule" component, showing day-by-day trip schedule is context subscriber. 
Now I want to delete one of the trip days (Day, also subscribing to the context is component rendered by Schedule Component on the Schedule list). And then magic happens:

when I do it right after logging in to the app, everything is working fine. But when I'll refresh the page and delete another day, context state (which as I said, holds all the data, including Days on schedule list) changes (checked via developer tools) but Schedule component is not re-rendering itself, so deleted element remains visible. 
But as I said, state changes, and everything is working fine without page refresh before deleting operation. Also when I switch to another tab (Schedule is just one of the tabs, I've got for example Costs and Notes tab on the navbar rendering Costs and Notes components), and then go back to the Schedule tab it re-renders and everything is looking fine, component is showing info accordingly to context state.

Code works like this: deletion (context function ) is triggered by delete icon click in Day.js (context subscriber), Day.js is rendered by Schedule.js (context subscriber too).

In Context.js

```
... context functions ...
    //WRAPPER FOR DELETE FUNCTIONS
    delete(url, deleteFunc) {
        this.requestsApi.request(url, "DELETE", null)
        .then(response => {
            if(response.status===204) {
                deleteFunc();
            } else {
                this.toggleRequestError(true);
            }
        })
        .catch( err => {
            console.log(err);
            this.toggleRequestError(true);
        });
    }

    deleteDay = (id, tripId) => {
        let newTrip = this.state.userData.trips.find((trip => trip.id === 
         tripId));
        newTrip.days = newTrip.days.filter(day => day.id !== id)

        this.updateTrip(newTrip);
    }

    updateTrip = (newTrip) => {
        let trips = this.state.userData.trips;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            userData : {
                ...prevState.userData,
                trips: trips.map(trip => {
                    if(trip.id !== newTrip.id)
                        return trip;
                    else
                        return newTrip;
                    })
                }
            }
        ));
    }

...
```

In Schedule.js

```
... in render's return ...
<ul>
    {this.trip.days.map((day,index) => {
         return <DayWithContext 
            inOverview={false} 
            key={index} 
            number={index} 
            day={day} 
            tripId={this.trip.id}    
         />
     })}
</ul>
....
```

In Day.js (delete icon)

```
...
<img 
    src={Delete} 
    alt="Delete icon" 
    className="mr-2" 
    style={this.icon}
    onClick={() => {
             this.props.context.delete(
             `/days/${this.props.day.id}`, 
             () => this.props.context.deleteDay(this.props.day.id, 
                   this.props.tripId)
             );
    }}
/>
...
```

Anyone is having any idea what's going on and why Schedule can be not re-rendered after deletion done after page refresh? And even if context state changes? Only idea I have for now is that this is some kind of a bug...

//UPDATE
In Schedule component, in function componentWillReceiveProps() I console log props.context.trip[0].day[0] - first day. It's not an object, just plain text, so its not evaluated "as I click on it in the console". 
Before I delete it, console logs first item. After I delete it, console logs second item (so now it's first item on the list) so props given to Schedule are changing, but no render is triggered... What the hell is going on there?

//UPDATE 2
I've also noticed that when I switch to Schedule component from another component, it works good (for example I'm refreshing the page on /costs endpoint then click Schedule tab on navbar menu which leads to /schedule). But when I refresh the page when on /schedule endpoint, this "bug" occurs and component is not re-rendering.

//Render from Context:

```
...
    render() {        
        const {
            isLoggedIn,
            wasLoginChecked,
            userData,
            isLogoutSuccesfulActive,
            isLogoutUnSuccesfulActive,
            isDataErrorActive,
            isRequestErrorActive,
            isDataLoaded
        } = this.state;

        const context =  {
            isLoggedIn,
            wasLoginChecked,
            isLogoutSuccesfulActive,
            isLogoutUnSuccesfulActive,
            isDataErrorActive,
            isRequestErrorActive,
            userData,
            isDataLoaded,
            requestsApi : this.requestsApi,
            toggleLogin : this.toggleLogin,
            checkLogin: this.checkLogin,
            setUserData: this.setUserData,
            loadData: this.loadData,
            addTrip: this.addTrip,
            delete: this.delete,
            deleteDay: this.deleteDay,
            deleteActivity: this.deleteActivity,
            deleteTrip: this.deleteTrip,
            updateTrip: this.updateTrip,
            uncheckLogin: this.uncheckLogin,
            toggleLogoutSuccesful: this.toggleLogoutSuccesful,
            toggleLogoutUnSuccesful: this.toggleLogoutUnSuccesful,
            toggleRequestError: this.toggleRequestError,
            toggleDataError: this.toggleDataError
        };

        return (
            <Context.Provider value={context}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Context.Provider>
        )
    }
}

export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

-------------Context HOC:

```
export default function withContext(Component) {
    return function ContextComponent(props) {
        return (
            <Context.Consumer>
                {context => <Component {...props} context={context} />}
            </Context.Consumer>
    );
    }
}
```

Comment: in the `Schedule.js` you are using `this.trip`. How do you set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mutate your state.
In this place, you change an object in the state without using setState:

```
newTrip.days = newTrip.days.filter(day => day.id !== id)
```

And then in your map function, you always return the same objects (it is already updated).
So, to fix your issue you can try to change your `deleteDay` method:

```
   deleteDay = (id, tripId) => {
        const trip = this.state.userData.trips.find((trip => trip.id === 
         tripId));
        const newTrip = {...trip, days: trip.days.filter(day => day.id !== id)};

        this.updateTrip(newTrip);
    }
```

UPDATE:
You have one more issue in your `Schedule` component.

You need to get current trip dynamically, don't set it in the constructor:

Try this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getTrip = this.getTrip.bind(this);
}
getTrip() {
    return this.props.context.userData.trips.find(trip => {
        return `${trip.id}`===this.props.match.params.id;
    });
}
render() {
    const trip = this.getTrip();

    return (
        ...
        <ul>
            {trip.days.map((day,index) => {
                return <DayWithContext 
                    inOverview={false} 
                    key={day.id} 
                    number={index} 
                    day={day} 
                    tripId={trip.id}    
                />
            })}
        </ul>
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer - I have forgotten that = is not copying an array. I fixed this by using:
const trips = Array.from(this.state.userData.trips);
let newTrip = trips.find((trip => trip.id === tripId));

But it still didn't solve my problem.  Context state gets updated, but Schedule component stays the same. When it's my first time seeying the app after login - its working ok. But when I refresh the page (session keeps me logged in) and do the same action on any other element on the list nothing happens. State changes behind the courtain, but no render is triggered...

Comment: the code you just show doesn't fix the issue with data mutation. If you try to change your `newTrip` variable after your code, you will also change the trip in your state.
Try this code:
`const arr = [{foo: "bar"}]; const newArr = Array.from(arr); newArr[0].foo = "baz"; console.log(arr[0].foo);` (sorry for the formatting, comments don't allow to use beauty formatting)
You see, the `Array.from` doesn't create new objects, it just copies links to original ones.
You need to do exactly the same as I show you in my answer, you need to create a new object for your `newTrip`.

Comment: also the potential bug I see in your Schedule.js. You need to use `day.id` as key for your component:
`key={day.id}`

Comment: Oh, so I've been mislead by some website with Array.from. I've done all you said, also changed first line in updateTrip to  const trips = [...this.state.userData.trips]. Still not working. I've also changed the key (why, by the way?). If you're still willing to help you can check out my update note in the bottom of main question- problem is elsewhere, because state is changed, component receives new props, but it's not re-rendered :/

Comment: about keys check [react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Comment: Here's github repo with schedule:
https://github.com/hayanawama/tripPlannerProject/blob/master/tripplanner-frontend/src/components/applicationPage/modules/Schedule/Schedule.js

Comment: Also I've simplified explanation of what's going on in structure of my app for better and simpler understanding. There are Activities under Day Component too, but it doesn't matter, deleting one or another gives the same bug.

Comment: Thanks man!!!!!!!!!!! Works like charm now. Made your function an arrow one though withouth binding in constructor.  Thanks for your time, I learned a lot from this conversation. Seems like I have to read a lot about component lifecycle and React in general. But now I don't understand why it even worked in the first place (without page refresh) as trip was fixed all the time :D One more question, would placing the function inside shouldComponentUpdate result with the same effect?

Comment: you can place any function inside `shouldComponentUpdate`. The only thing you should know about `shouldComponentUpdate` is that the first parameter will be `newProps` and old props can access via `this.props`. So if you define something like `getTrip` inside of `shouldComponentUpdate` than you will get only old `trip`.